# Having a global permissions service check for ng-disabled or ng-hide

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to have a global permission check for certain elements in my markup, but I don't necessarily want/need to have my controller be aware of it. The permission check itself is quite arbitrary, as the back-end services will block any unauthorised access... this is just for hiding/disabling controls.

Essentially, I have a permission service which will check if the current user has a required permission. I'd like to call on this service in my markup like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-disabled="$permissions.check('edit-user')" />
```

So my questions are:

1. Is this bad practice?
2. How do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for example in my case. im using $rootScope property for checking the premmission, I think in your case insead of property in $rootSCope you can have a functions which will be return to you permission, and I think yes if its global think, its not a bad practice to do it in rootScope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can do it like that, but I prefer another approach. Instead of adding a `$permissions` property to each `$scope` (or to the `$rootScope`), you can just use [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

The permissions filter would look something like this:

```
app.filter('hasPermission', function(permissionsSvc) {
  return function(input, invert) {
    var hasPermission = permissionsSvc.check(input);
    return (invert ? !hasPermission : hasPermission);
  };
});
```

And the permissions service:

```
app.factory('permissionsSvc', function() {
  return {
    check: function(permission) {
      // do the validation here and return true or false
    }
  };
});
```

On the markup:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-disabled="'edit-user' | hasPermission:true" />
```

The `true` after the filter is to invert the condition (second argument of the filter function), since we want to "disable if the user doesn't have the permission". That's just one way to do it, you could, for example, define another filter like `hasNoPermission` that would do the opposite of the `hasPermission` filter... it's a matter of tastes.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eXdmsl06SJnA1QOUj1do?p=preview)